# Get item index of a list within Select statement

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to index the item list with its position after grouping

```
var result = from i in items
             group i by i.name into g
             select new { groupname = g.Key, 
                          index = //need to get the index of the item
                        };
```

How to get the item index of a list using linq/lambda?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but I would definitely advice to use methods instead of syntax-based query.

```
var results = items.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                   .Select((g, i) => new { product = g.Key, index = i });
```

Or if you'd like to get indexes from source lift for all items within every group:

```
var results = items.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.x.name)
                   .Select(g => new {
                                   product = g.Key,
                                   indexes = g.Select(x => x.i).ToList()
                               });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var idx = 0;
var result = from i in items
             group i by i.name into g
             select new { product = g.Key, 
                          index = idx++
                        };
```